# BlackMATE theme - alt-tab window switcher selection color

Tags: gnome, themes, mate, ubuntu-mate

In the BlackMATE theme the alt-tab window switcher selection frame is a black rectangle against a dark brown background. How can I change this to a brighter color?

[image]

I don't see an option in any of the configuration utilities, but I suppose it would be fairly simple to modify the source code. So I have the source code but don't see what to modify.

I'm using the stock BlackMATE with Ubuntu 18.10. Here is a listing of the BlackMATE subdirectories. Are they all relevant? I suppose gtk2.0 is not so I suppose that there are other directories that have no effect on my system.

```
./gtk-3.0
./apps
./gtk-2.0
./metacity-1
./unity
./cinnamon
```

Is there detailed documentation somewhere I should be looking?

Comment: @DKBose Well that's interesting. Yes I am using BlackMATE -- at least that is what I have selected through Look & Feel / Appearance. With all customizable settings set to BlackMATE --  for a year or so. I'm only now wondering if there's anything I can do about this. Just a niggle really, but...

Comment: @DKBose Desktop is MATE. What is yours?

Comment: @DKBoseVery curious. I have this deployed to three machines, all are the same. Two native and one VBox VM on a Windows host. These were upgraded in place from 18.04. I wonder if that's a difference. I'll install a VM from a fresh download and see. Unless it's a repo issue. I'm using the Canadian.

Comment: I haven't been able to get a screenshot of the switcher dialog. I get only the active window beneath it -- I have the same colors with the new 18.10 I just installed to a VM. I have a Debian 9 VM with MATE too -- same thing. Is your BlackMATE on a MATE desktop? I'll post on the Ubuntu MATE page see what they have to say.

Comment: @DKBose Ah! Excellent. Done.